# Nginx HTTP and 2 TCP on port 80

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, socket.io

I am doing something where I have two websockets, one for the client and one for the server are being used alongside an HTTP node server at port 3000, am I doing something wrong here? Or is this not possible?

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

}
```

api.js

```
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';
const  socket = openSocket('ws://example.com/ws');

function roomSubscribe(roomId, cb) {
    socket.on('roomInfo', data => cb(null, data));
    socket.emit('getRoom', {'roomId': roomId});
}

function sendMessage(content) {
    socket.emit('sendMessage', content);
}

export { roomSubscribe, sendMessage };
```

Comment: They can run on same port

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do some modify:
delete the upgrade settings in location /

And notice you request a path which is **/ws**, but the location regex in nginx.conf is **/ws/**. keep it same.

use this to get a socket :

```
socket = openSocket("ws://example.com/ws/", {transports: ['websocket']})
```

Add this code to see whether the ws connection is build.

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('connected!');
});
```

Comment: Port 3000 goes to my App/http and port 8000 goes to my server

Comment: then in location / , do not use the upgrade . it is used for ws connection build.

Comment: I'm still getting these two errors:
`websocket.js:6 WebSocket connection to 'ws://example.com/sockjs-node/063/fabw334n/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400` and

`http://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LttlOsD 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: What? openSocket is just what I'm calling the socket.io-client

Comment: What are you talking about? of course openSocket isn't in there, i'm assigning socket.io-client to the variable openSocket

Comment: is the ws connection build successfully ?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to

Comment: I'm getting 502 to the :8000 and a 400 to the same host, when socket.io switches protocols?
Self: `ws://dev.charplay.com/sockjs-node/082/ewj21amf/websocket error 400`
Server: `ws://dev.charplay.com/ws/?EIO=3&transport=websocket error 502`

Comment: do you fix the /ws and /ws/, 502 maybe caused by this. keep same

Comment: maybe your server listened  8000 has some problem, use 'netstat -tupln | grep :8000' command as root to check that is the server running on 8000

Comment: It's working on 8000 though, I can just connect my client to port 8000